# Change UI parameters using thread in separate class

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, oop

I would like to be able to change an element of the main form inside a thread declared in a separated class (In this case I want to change a label text).
I tried the following code:

**Form1**:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Public counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim SecondClassObject As New SecondClass()

    End Sub
End Class
```

**SecondClass**:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class SecondClass

    Public Thread As New Thread(AddressOf Increment)

    Public counter As Integer = 0

    Sub New()
        Thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub Increment()
        While True
            Form1.Label1.Text = counter
            counter += 1
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

If I do the same thing using a thread but in the form code itself than the label text will change:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Public counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf Increment)
        thread.Start()

    End Sub

    Sub Increment()
        While True
            Label1.Text = counter
            counter += 1
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

How should I do in order to archieve the same result using a thread in a separated class?

Comment: Please do not put programming language names in the title. The tags already indicate which language you're using. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I do want to point out that you need to use an Invoke/Callback to safely set the label's text from the secondary thread.  I don't know if you're doing that in your actual code base, but wanted to specify anyways.

Now, focused on the actual question, I believe that the easiest way to do as requested is to pass a reference to the original instance of Form1 to your SecondClass.  Having a reference to the parent, means that you would be able to manipulate the parent's publicly exposed elements as needed.

Consider the below:

```
    Public Class Form1 
        Public counter As Integer = 0

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load        
            Dim secondClass As New SecondClassObject(me)        
        End Sub

        Delegate  Sub SetTextCallback (value as String)
        Public Sub SetText (value as string)
           if me.Label1.InvokeRequired Then 
               dim d as New SetTextCallback(addressOf SetText)
               Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {value})
            Else 
               me.label1.text = value 
            End If 
        End Sub 
    End Class

   Public Class SecondClassObject 
        private _parent as Form1 
        private myThread As New Thread(AddressOf Increment)

        Public Sub New (byref p as Form1)
           me._parent = p 
           myThread.Start()
        End Sub 

        Sub Increment()
            While True
               Me._parent.SetText(counter)
               counter += 1
            End While
        End Sub
   End Class
```

What is happening is that the a reference to the parent is passed into the second class as a constructor, doing so allows us to interact with the parent from the second class.

Now, that is one way, but other options do exist. Things such as specialized events/handlers or wiring up databinding between the Form1.Label1 and a property exposed from the SecondClassObject.  Even a singleton pattern, where the value to be incremented is shared between all instances, so when the SecondClassObject increments it, Form1 would be aware and know to update Label1.

Also, please note that the above code is for example purposes, and is missing things such as a defined declaration for Label1.

Answer (score 0):

On windows it's not possible to change the UI from a non UI thread.

It looks like that you have to use Control.Invoke or better Control.BeginInvoke.

The problem with using Control.Invoke is that it's executed on the UI thread and the calling thread waits for completion. Which would be bad when your background worker continusly does some computations.

Comment: And how is he supposed to marshal the event to the UI thread without invoking? If he _doesn't_ invoke the event will be running on the background thread, meaning he still can't access any UI elements. -- There's nothing wrong with invoking, and it's definitely _not_ not the way Windows was designed. To say that Windows was designed with events in mind isn't quite true because it is hard to narrow it down to such a small thing, since there were so many things to have in mind when it was designed.

Comment: A more accurate term would be _signaling_, which is done heavily by the system (asynchronous I/O and what not). Signaling is different from events in that it signals a specific application or a specific thread either that something has happened or that it should do something. Each application/thread usually get its own set of data from the signal. Events aren't instance-specific like this since they basically just shout the same things to everyone who wants to listen: _"Hey, something happened!"_.

Comment: Invoking to the UI actually just sends a message to the window telling it to execute a certain method on its thread. This is a great example of _signaling_, as well as why this is definitely _one_ of the things that Windows was designed for. || For the record, if you don't want to block the background thread until the message has been sent and the method call finished, you can use `BeginInvoke` instead which posts the message without waiting for it to be processed.

Comment: By the way, a `Thread` is marked as `sealed` (`NotInheritable` in VB.NET) so you cannot inherit it (nor is there any reason to).

Comment: @VisualVincent Event is the term used in windows, which also is the way to send messages from one thread to another. Using Invoke is something completly different then using an event to get data from thread A to thread B. Btw.: When inheriting from thread is disallowed in VB.NET, just doing C#, then the not preferred way has to be used.

Comment: An event cannot be inherited in C# either. It is marked as `sealed` by the framework, one shouldn't need to inherit it. Also, no: Invoking **is not** something different to sending messages from thread A to thread B, **because that's exactly what it does**. Sending messages from one thread to another is not using (or at least should not be) _events_ because events are used to notify subscribers, any subscriber, when something happens, and always with the same data. Signals on the other hand can also be used to instruct a thread to do something, and its data can be specific for each thread.

Comment: _"Event is the term used in windows, which also is the way to send messages from one thread to another"_ - Could you please show me some documentation for both of these statements? Also note that signals can be used as events (infact events are signals that distribute the exact same data to every subscriber), but an event cannot be used as a signal.

Comment: _"But when sending an event with delegates under the hood a message will be put into the UI thread message queue and the caller returns immediately."_ - This is also not true. Mere delegates cannot be used to marshal calls to the UI because they're only a wrapper of a function pointer. Invoking a delegate does the exact same thing as invoking a function: `DoSomething()`. What you're describing though is the exact process of [**`Control.BeginInvoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334867(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: `Control.Invoke()` and `Control.BeginInvoke()` both queue a message on the UI thread. The difference between them is that `Invoke()` _sends_ the message and waits for it to be processed (waits for the method to be executed), whereas `BeginInvoke()` _posts_ the message and returns immediately. These are one of the few, correct ways to marshal calls to the UI thread. There's no reason that they **wouldn't** be preferred. Which one to use depends on what you need.

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment that should be _"A **thread** cannot be inherited in C# either ..."_

Comment: @VisualVincent Here you can see the terms used by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events and also the preferred way to change data inside a form by another thread. ;) You can also see that you have to use delegates to use events in .NET... So the terms i use are the correct ones. You have to adopt the code to a forms project by yourself.

Comment: That’s just about .NET events in general, it hasn’t got anything to do with threads, thread-safety nor passing data between different threads. You most certainly can not use that to marshal calls nor pass data to the UI thread. Event handlers aren’t called on different threads by themselves, they’re called in the same thread that raised the event. You have to marshal the call(s) to the UI thread yourself using `(Begin)Invoke`. Neither events nor delegates are thread-safe by design.

Comment: I conducted a simple test using events and multithreading, give it a try: https://pastebin.com/jB1MSPEq

Comment: Hm. I'm was sure that I've done it this way some time ago, but it looks like I was wrong. I've to check code at home. Edited answer, I'm sure that we've had a background worker and just send events to the UI about status changes because our worker did a lot of computations.

Comment: I think we've had a list which fires events on changes. The UI registered to these events and the list was given to the thread, who changed the list.

Comment: A background worker sounds about right. Its `ProgressChanged` event is marshalled to the UI.

Comment: In response to your edit: `Invoke` blocks the calling thread, `BeginInvoke` doesn’t. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent Changed, and refreshed knowledge. :)